# Horizontal scrolling only to the right

Tags: jquery, scroll

So I want to be able to scroll a page with the mouse wheel, I used this:

```
<script>
 $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0) { window.scrollBy(-80,0); 
    } else window.scrollBy(80,0) ; 
});
</script>
```

but no matter which direction is scrolling the page it's only going to the right, any advice?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no delta argument, only the event, and that has `event.originalEvent.wheelDelta` that you can hook into

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function(event) {

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) { 
        window.scrollBy(-80,0); 
    } else {
        window.scrollBy(80,0); 
    }

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5hwv7/1/)